Name of a movie where a mother saves her son from her toxic/problematic girlfriend?
Does anybody know what is the name of a movie where a mother saves her teen son from a problematic girlfriend who first appears as a sweet girl but later introduces him to drink, to cut himself and to miss his classes?
More details: 
Both of them met at a high school, she was new to this school since she kept changing schools because of her problematic behavior, the girl came from foster parents etc. She had a history of making her boyfriends commit suicide for her.

I'm pretty sure there are at least a dozen films with this plot.  Can you please be more specific? What country/language? When do you remember seeing it? Was it made for TV or in theaters? Any more specific details about the plot, something that sets this film apart from others?

I remember watching this movie on Verizon Fios (on Demand) it was about a teen girl who came from a foster parents with a really sad background. She was new to this high school where she met this boy with whom then she started a toxic relationship.
She introduced him to drugs, and especially cutting, she had a history of making her ex boyfriends committed suicide by giving them a ring. The guy's mother was able to save her son from this crazy girlfriend.

Anybody? I been looking for the name of this movie for over 2 hours now...

You just edited the post... do the same thing to add what you just said into the body of your question... also, could you just look at your viewing history to see what the film was? Also, be patient.  It will likely take us much longer than 2 hours to find it... unless @Walt is here. He's magical. But he needs enough information. You still haven't even addressed my request for more info, you just reiterated exactly what's already up there except for saying you watched it on demand.

I don't have Verizon Fios anymore...  I am pretty sure maybe some of you watched this movie before... If you guys need more details please let me know.

@Catija That's nice of you, but I'm no genie... That said, this sounds a lot like the plot of Lifetime's A Mother's Nightmare from 2012. :P

Huh, this reminded me of Thirteen (2003), the only difference is the main character is a boy in this one.

Sounds a lot like Lifetime's A Mother's Nightmare from 2012 with Annabeth Gish as the mom.

Vanessa moves fast to claim Chris for her own, taking his time away and distancing him from his family and friends. His mom, Maddie, is disturbed by their sudden relationship and when she discovers a secret of Vanessa's and she uses all her resources to convince Chris to end it.

Vanessa is a troubled teen that drives her boyfriends to suicide and tries the same tricks on Chris. Here's a trailer (rather low quality, sorry):




you are a genius! how are you able to find those movies so quick? Thanks to Catija too!

@NikkiTech No problem, but if this is the correct answer, please approve it with the check mark to resolve the question.
